# Wordpress Child Pages' Featured Image Descriptio

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this code to display child pages' features images;

```
<?
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');

if ( $child_pages ) :
foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) :
    setup_postdata( $pageChild );
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'thumbnail');
    if($thumbnail == "") continue; // Skip pages without a thumbnail
?>
    <div class="child-thumb">
      <a href="<?= get_permalink($pageChild->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?=     $pageChild->post_title ?>">
        <?= $pageChild->post_title ?><br /><?= $thumbnail ?>
      </a>
    </div>
<?
endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

And I'd like to display the featured images' descriptions on the parent page as well.

FYI, this is the web page;

http://storyville.jonmarkoff.com/storyvillewp/our-work/

Thanks!

Comment: r u getting output or what, if not means what error you got it from above code ?

Comment: I'm getting only thumbnails, without their descriptions.

Comment: the_content(); or get_the_content(); inside the loop if it works i can paste the code

Comment: Hm, but I don't want to het the content of the post, the description of the thumbnail.

Comment: `<?php the_post_thumbnail();
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content; ?>`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working...It gets the content of the parents page, not the child pages' thumbnail descriptions

Comment: http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2010/02/12/wordpress-get-post-images-and-the_post_thumbnail-caption/ http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-caption-with-the_post_thumbnail?replies=12

Comment: I followed the first link and it worked!

Comment: Cheers it works for you. . .